# Facebook Authentication iOS using Storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, facebook, storyboard

Is there a good way to implement Facebook Authentication using Storyboard rather than xib files?  It seems that the tutorial on the facebook developer site simply uses xib files.

Right now my code crashes at initWithNibName calls because my current project only uses Storyboard.

Thanks!

Code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    self.mainViewController = [[MyViewController alloc]
                               initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];

    self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                          initWithRootViewController:self.mainViewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

I'm getting this code from this site:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios-sdk-tutorial/authenticate/

Comment: Facebook code stays the same whether you use XIB or Storyboards. Can you share the error you are getting? `initWithNibName` does not get called when using Storyboard, `initWithCoder` gets called instead.

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle

Comment: Can you pls copy code that tries to open xib file?

Comment: Hi Yas, I've edited the question and added the code snippet. sorry it was missing.

Comment: The above code isn't using a storyboard. Is your project a storyboard based project?

Comment: Yes, my project is storyboard based.  The above code snippet is from the facebook tutorial that I am trying to adopt to my project.

Answer (score 2):

That tutorial is useless if you want to use storyboard because 90% of the tutorial is about setting up your user interface (not Facebook specific stuff). If you want to perform this tutorial with storyboards then setup your own UI first, then understand what they are doing when the Login button is pressed (and Logout).

The only things you need to do in your app delegate are:

1. Add the application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation: method
2. Modify applicationDidBecomeActive: as they suggest
3. Check the state of the session when your app starts to determine if you show your login view or go straight to the main view (although you could also do this on the load of your first view).

You can put the code to open your facebook session (login) and respond to changes in the session state in the app delegate or elsewhere. Personally, I prefer to handle all the session management in a separate FB management class so as not to muddle up the app delegate with Facebook related code.

Your best bet is to just do this tutorial without storyboards to understand what they are doing and then adopt that into your own app, and/or read [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/login/) instead to understand the FBSession object.

Comment: Thanks Joel.  What actually worked for me was being able to reference my storyboard viewcontrollers via their storyboard id's rather than initwithnibname.

Answer (score 0):

I realized I could access my view controllers via the storyboard id's.

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
        UIViewConroller* myViewController = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyStoryboardID"];
```